# Equivalent of safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame.origin using topLayoutGuide

Tags: ios, iphone, ios10, ios11

`topLayoutGuide` property was depreciated for iOS 11+ and now we have to use `safeAreaLayoutGuide`(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621367-toplayoutguide).

How can I get the value of `safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame.origin.y` using `topLayoutGuide` to target < iOS 11?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the same value using `self.view.layoutMarginsGuide.layoutFrame.origin.y * self.view.layoutMarginsGuide.layoutFrame.origin.x`.